# Arduino Mega 2560 stuck at uploading

Tags: arduino, atmega, programming, avrdude

I have two [Arduino Mega 2560](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardMega2560) boards, both gives errors when trying to upload sketches (I bought the second board thinking its a fault with the first one, but same thing happen with the new board).

The new board started to fail after a day! The boards worked perfectly in the first few (~10) uploads. I can't imagine how this happen, but it's like the board is *dying* with time! The same sketch, which could be easily uploaded previously, can't be uploaded now.

If you ask me what happens, It starts uploading and gets **stucked** at about 95% of the progress. *(please see the following image)*

[image]

I found this is the exact issue mentioned [in this thread](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php?PHPSESSID=7c1bc6015ca657cf9ab28bf6a7c3218b&topic=109417.0). I found several other posts too regarding this matter so I hope I'm not the only one to face this. But unfortunately, still I couldn't find any working solution.

Can anyone please suggest me a proper workaround? At least, will downgrading the Arduino IDE will work, *permanently*?

---

Arduino IDE version, 1.0.1

Comment: Is it really on com26? Have a look in device manager.

Comment: yes, i've done that mistake a long time ago..

Comment: Are you using a programmer or the bootloader?

Comment: Also - enable the output.verbose option in the preference file and see what the bootloader is saying.

Answer (score 5):

You are using IDE 1.0.1. Most probably the problem is with the stk500v2 protocol used for uploading to Arduino Mega. It's changed to more reliable 'wiring' protocol in v.1.0.2.

You shouldn't downgrade but upgrade to a latest version. http://arduino.cc/en/main/software

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are not complete. The best thing to do is to burn a new bootloader into the Arduino Mega 2560 board, together with the newest Arduino IDE, and remove all old things that are on your computer.
Do you have a programmer ? You should get one.

The trouble with the '!!!' is fixed, and also a number of other bugs have been fixed in the bootloader for the Arduino Mega 2560.

Remove the Arduino IDE. Delete the C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino folder, because there could still be files that mess up the new version.
Remove all the usb-serial drivers that you have installed. It is not normal to have COM26. I have COM5.
Remove Java completely. The Arduino has its own mini version of Java, and an other Java could get in the way.
Find the hidden "arduino15" folder(s). Delete those folders. This is important, don't think you can skip this step.

After that you can start with a fresh new install.
Install the newest Arduino IDE from the official website: https://www.arduino.cc/en/main/software
When using a cheap clone board with the CH340G, use the drivers of the official website: http://www.wch.cn/download/CH341SER_EXE.html
Use a programmer and the Arduino IDE to burn the newest bootloader into the Arduino Mega 2560. When you use the Arduino IDE to burn the bootloader, then also the fuses will be set to their proper values.

When there is a problem with the reset (the reset is needed to connect to the bootloader to upload a sketch), then get rid of that board.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, upload get stuck on my Arduino Mega 2560. In my case the issue was a string with more than one exclamation point!!!

Removed and worked again.

**NOTE:**
This did not upload: `Serial.println("Hello!!!");`
This did upload: `Serial.println("Hello!");`

**NOTE 2:**
 
"!!!" seems to be an escape sequence to put the bootloader into "monitor" or "command prompt" mode (see: [avr-developers.com/bootloaderdocs/index.html](http://avr-developers.com/bootloaderdocs/index.html))

Comment: It's highly unlikely that the extra exclamation marks are the cause here. If anything, it points to some sort of intermittent connection issue.

Comment: As I said: in my case this was the issue!

Comment: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=49591.0

Comment: I never said your symptom didn't go away. I'm saying that it's unlikely that the extra 2 bytes of 0x21 were the *cause* of what you were seeing.

Comment: I'm not an Arduino expert, but may be other people are: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,46966.0.html#0

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/arduino/issues/detail?id=392

Comment: http://www.avr-developers.com/bootloaderdocs/index.html

Comment: huh. fair enough. You should edit your answer to include *why* that particular string is an issue (it seems to be an escape sequence to put the bootloader into some sort of interactive mode). If you do that, I'll be able to remove my -1.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAzjO4v7oF4

This guys says to manually hit the Mega reset pushbutton just as the green progress bar on the IDE from the compilation hits the right end. Another hint was to set the Preferences for Verbose (both compiler and bootloader), which consumes a bit more time with extra messages. Since it worked forme, this would seem to indicate a timing problem with the Reset pulse being too short (not getting recognized) on some systems using the CH340/341 USB to serial chips. The symptoms and his fix seem to say the hardware Reset pulse is too short in some cases, but there is enough of a timing window (in software) for the IDE to accept a manual reset if you get it at just the right time. I don't have a schematic or scope handy to check this for sure, but it may also be that the coupling cap to the Reset line from the CH part to the Mega2560 Reset is too small. Might try bridging/paralleling with a leaded 0.1uF cap across the SMD cap to see if it makes any difference, and solder one in if it fixes. Best Wishes

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution:

Unplug the USB cable from my monitor / usb hub and plug it DIRECTLY into my motherboard USB port and VIOLA!  Sketches are uploading no problemo!

:)

Comment: Considering the question is 5 years old, I think the OP and technology have moved on.